# free() invalid pointer - freeing array of pointers fails

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I have been debugging a piece of legacy code, running on an XScale (arm v5te) System with linux, that crashes reproducible.

I have debugged using gdb and set MALLOC_CHECK_ to 1. It's a lot of code, so just some snippets:

We have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
...clipped..
    char **data_column_list;
    /** data column count */
    int data_column_cnt;
...clipped
} csv_t;
```

We initialize the columns in a function, putting them in a variable "columns"

```
/* Allocating memory for pointer to every register id */
columns = (char **) malloc(column_cnt * sizeof(char *));

column_cnt = 0;
/* loop over all sensors */
for(i=0; i<cfg.sen_cnt; i++) {
    /* loop over all registers */
    for(j=0; j<cfg.sen_list[i]->data_cnt; j++) {
        /* Storing all the pointers to id */
        columns[column_cnt++] = cfg.sen_list[i]->data_list[j]->id;
    }
}
```

In another function, what happens is this:

```
/* free the previous list */
csv_free(lc_csv);

lc_csv->data_column_list = columns;
lc_csv->data_column_cnt = column_cnt;
```

csv_free being:

```
void csv_free(csv_t *csv) {
    if(csv->data_column_cnt > 0)
        free(csv->data_column_list);

    csv->data_column_cnt = 0;
}
```

Now, there is another function, building the whole "cfg"/config structure, that contains these ids.
Code frome above: cfg.sen_list[i]->data_list[j]->id; where cfg is a struct, sen_list is an array of pointers to structs, data_list is an array of pointers to other structs, that contain a string "id".

Whe the program gets a signal SIGUSR1, the config is being updated. All of these data_list and sen_list structs are being freed, then new ones are generated.
Then with the first function, new collumns of ids are generated and put into the csv structure, but the old list is being freed before.

Thats where it crashes. In csv_free.

```
*** glibc detected *** /root/elv: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0001ae88 ***
```

I thought it should be like this. You have an array of pointers. When you free the pointers, you have to free the pointer, pointing to a set of pointers (the array).
Or put in code terms, the above situation should be analog to:

```
char **ar = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
char *xn = malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // Do for 0 to n strings
...
ar[n] = xn; // Do for 0 to n strings
...do stuff...
free(xn); // Do for 0 to n strings
free(ar);
```

When the structs, containing the id strings, are freed, I still have my pointer arrays with (invalid) pointers, not null pointers:

```
(gdb) p csv
$40 = {sysid = 222, ip = '\0' <repeats 49 times>, 
    module = "elv_v2", '\0' <repeats 14 times>, format_type = 1, msg_id = 0, 
    data_column_list = 0x1ae88, data_column_cnt = 10, pub_int = 30, 
    line_cnt = 0, pub_seq = -1, format = 0x18260}
(gdb) p csv.data_column_list[0]
$41 = 0x1b378 "0"
```

But I get the above error message (or SIGABRT without the MALLOC_CHECK_).
I don't understand this at all. I have to free this array of pointers, or it will become a memory leak. There is no other call of free before that, that I could find. I don't know why csv.data_column_list is considered an invalid pointer.
Valgrind is unfortunately not availiable on arm v5te :(

Have been debugging this for hours and hours and would be happy for any help.
Thank you very much,
Cheers, 
Ben

UPDATE:

I'm wondering if it could be connected to some "scope" issue. There is almost identical code in another application, which works. The function which crashes, "csv_free" is used by both programs (statically linked). The only difference is, that the struct containing the pointer to be freed is declared and defined normally in the working program and declared as `external` and defined in another file than main.c
Calling "free" manually in main.c works, while calling "csv_free" crashes. Riddle me this...

Comment: Did you try running it with valgrind?

Comment: If you breakpoint just after the mallocs, and just before the frees, do all the pointer values match?

Comment: you should check `csv` is `NULL` or not in `csv_free`, and after freeing `csv` assign it with NULL. This will protect you from doing `csv->member` when `csv` is NULL or some garbage.

Comment: You said you're freeing pointers after SIGUSR1 is received. Is that inside the signal handler? SIGUSR1 can be delivered at any time, so it may be unsafe to malloc or free inside the signal handler. If the signal is delivered when the program is inside another call to malloc/free, you could corrupt the heap.

Comment: Thank you guys for reading and commenting!

@Als - as I said, Valgrind is not availiable for this platform. I was thinking about running it on my x86-64 machine, but I would need to recreate the environment to make the software work, e.g., making virtual serial ports and supplying infos to them. But that is quite a lot of effort.

Comment: @phoxis - technically, the data_column_cnt is set to zero when the array is freed, so to check this should be sufficient.

For the rest, I will have to wait til Monday when I'm in the office to do more tests.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes they do. I also checked the content of memory with gdb's x command. The 2 bytes before and afterwards also don't change, so no buffer overflow or underrun :/

Comment: @JayConrod Well, the actual free is in subsequent function calls, but those happen inside the signal handler. So I guess yes? 
But I can pretty much rule out, that there is another malloc/free going on, because the main loop does not contain anything like that.

Comment: Thou should not call malloc() nor free(0 from a signal handler. (malloc and free are not reentrant)

Comment: Yeah, what wildplasser said. It doesn't matter whether you're calling directly from the signal handler or from another function called by the signal handler. If any non-reentrant function is called inside a signal handler, you will get mysterious errors like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over my old questions I saw this. I can't really verify, since I don't work at that company anymore, but thinking of other issues we had, I think wildplasser was right.

Calling any large functions from within signal handlers is a bad idea. Especially if you haven't check whether everything you do is reentrant. It was legacy code, so at least it's not completely my fault ;)

Nowadays I would set a flag in the signal handler and call the routine in my main loop, when that flag is set (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

9 out of 10 times when I run into free() errors the problem actually started in the allocation or initialization, so let's verify that a bit:

1. Where do you actually assign `columns` to `csv.data_columns_list` **before** you call `csv_free`? If it's uninitialized when you free(), that would explain the error.
2. In the second code block, if the initial column_cnt (which I guess is set 
   elsewhere?) is less than the column_cnt after the loop you would be writing outside the 
   array. One would hope MALLOC_CHECK_ would catch that, but what happens if you assert as 
   follows:

   ```
   /* Allocating memory for pointer to every register id */
   columns = (char **) malloc(column_cnt * sizeof(char *));

   int old_column_cnt = column_cnt;
   column_cnt = 0;
   /* loop over all sensors */
   for(i=0; i<cfg.sen_cnt; i++) {
       /* loop over all registers */
       for(j=0; j<cfg.sen_list[i]->data_cnt; j++) {
           /* Storing all the pointers to id */
           columns[column_cnt++] = cfg.sen_list[i]->data_list[j]->id;
       }
   }
   assert(old_column_cnt >= column_cnt);
   ```